# Is there a way to grab code from a PR with a deleted branch on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

On GitHub, I normally clone someone's fork or add it as a remote to download their changes. However, if the branch/fork is completely deleted, this isn't an option.

Yet, you are still able to view the changed files in the PR if you click the "Files changed" tab in the PR, even with the fork/branch deleted and the PR closed.

Is there a way to get a branch with those changes locally on my system? One idea would be to just manually recreate everything by copy-pasting the changes from the website, but this approach seems sub-optimal.

Comment: Under the hood, the PR *is* a branch; I don't recall how you get access to it, though.

Comment: You can restore the branch on PR page if you have appropriate permission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's relatively easy:

```
git fetch <remote-or-url> refs/pull/1234/head:refs/heads/pr1234
```

for instance will turn their (GitHub's) pull-request-#1234 commit(s) into your `pr1234` branch.

#### Background

The way this works is straightforward:

1. All names<sup>1</sup> in Git are *refs* or *references*.  That is, the branch name `master` is really just `refs/heads/master`; the tag name `v1.2` is really just `refs/tags/v1.2`; your remote-tracking `origin/master` is really just `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  Names that are *branch names* start with `refs/heads/`.  Git normally strips off the leading part of whatever kind of name it is, on the assumption that you'll know that `master` is a branch, `v1.2` is a tag, and `origin/master` is a remote-tracking name.
2. When you run `git fetch`, your Git obtains *their* commits (and other objects) by the name-and-hash-ID pairs that their Git shows to your Git.  Then it copies over any commits (and other objects) needed, so that your Git can update your remote-tracking name(s) and/or write entries into your Git's `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file and so on.  Last, it does a couple of things:

   - update your own refs, as directed; and
   - write `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.

   The `FETCH_HEAD` file is left behind for the `git pull` code, mainly; it's a bit of a historical artifact now that `git pull` has been rewritten in C.

The nice thing about refs is that, being divided into [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), you or anyone can invent your own.  The `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/` and `refs/remotes/` spaces are taken, as are `refs/bisect/` and `refs/replace/` and some others, but GitHub were able to use `refs/pull/`, which Git itself does not, to store *their* names.

In this `refs/pull/` space, GitHub insert the PR or issue number (these numbers are per-repository and otherwise global to the repository) followed by `/head` for the tip commit and `/merge` for the result of performing an unattended, automatic test `git merge`.  If the automatic merge *fails*, GitHub simply do not create the `merge` ref.  Hence if there is a PR with number 1234, `refs/pull/1234/head` exists; if that PR was successfully test-merged, `refs/pull/1234/merge` also exists, and if not, it does not.

Note that the conversion from their (GitHub's) *branch* names to your *remote-tracking* names is controlled by your own `remote.origin.fetch` configuration line, which defaults to:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This is a *refspec:* a pair of refs, separated by a colon, and optionally prefixed with a plus sign `+` (always used for this particular case).  That matches all of their *branch* names, as the left side or *source* pattern matches branch names.  It causes your Git to replace their branch names with your remote-tracking names, as the right side or *destination* pattern replaces `refs/heads/` with `refs/remotes/origin/` (keeping everything matched by `*` intact).

This means you can add:

```
+refs/pull/*/head:refs/heads/pr*
```

to your `remote.origin.fetch` refspecs, in your `.git/config`, so that `git fetch` will automatically, and almost always,<sup>2</sup> create or update your `prnumber` branches.  It will, however, potentially wreck any of your own personal `prnumber` branches that you created on your own, so be aware that if you do this, you must avoid naming branches `pr`-something (at least something numeric, but beware pruning; see footnote 2).

---

<sup>1</sup>The exceptions here are `HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, and the like.  While `FETCH_HEAD` works like a reference sometimes, the `FETCH_HEAD` file is particularly special in that it can contain multiple lines and some extra annotations; the others contain only (and exactly) one hash ID or one symbolic ref.

<sup>2</sup>"Always" is too strong, and even my slightly weasel worded *almost always* might be as well: any time you run `git fetch` with some refspec argument(s), that will override this default.  Your configured `remote.origin.fetch` settings are used only if you did not override them.  Remember how this interacts with `fetch.prune` or `git fetch -p`, too: the `*` in the destination now means Git will automatically *remove* matching refs that weren't written by the fetch action.

The ability to write `pr*` rather than, e.g., `pr/*`, depends on your Git vintage.  In some older versions of Git, glob-like `*` patterns in refspecs can only be used in "whole name component" ways, e.g., `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` is always OK in all Git versions, no matter how ancient, but sometimes `refs/heads/a*:refs/remotes/origin/a*` is not.